# How does find_first function work for an OCaml Set?

Tags: ocaml

I am struggling to understand why the following code does not find any matching result:

```
module IntPairs =
struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare (x0,y0) (x1,y1) =
    match Stdlib.compare x0 x1 with
      0 -> Stdlib.compare y0 y1
    | c -> c
end
module PairsSet = Set.Make(IntPairs) 
let m2 = PairsSet.(empty |> add (2,0) |> add (1,2) |> add (0,1)) 
let result = PairsSet.find_first_opt (fun (input,value) -> print_endline ("arg:"^(string_of_int input)^" val:"^(string_of_int value)); input=0) m2;;
match result with
| None -> "nope"
| Some _ -> "yep";;
```

My understanding based on the documentation:
https://ocaml.org/api/Set.S.html
is that the `find_first` function should traverse from the smallest element (in this case it would be the `(0,1)` pair) checking whether any element meets the condition in provided function.

It does not however work as described above since it starts from the greatest element `(2,0)` and checks only this one element. I have checked if the order of provided elements has any impact on how `find_first` function works and it does. If I rearrange the `m2` set so that the `(0,1)` element is first a match will be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This confused me a fair bit as well, but the key here is in "where `f` is a monotonically increasing function".

A [monotonically increasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) is a function which must not decrease (despite its name it must not necessarily increase). For a function returning a `bool`, like we have here, that means it cannot go from `true` to `false` as the input value increases.

Your function `fun (input, value) -> input = 0` is `true` only for a single value. It is false for any value below `0` and any value greater than `0`.

`find_first` is implemented such that it walks "downwards" as long as `f` returns `true`, and "upwards" as long as it returns `false`, thereby finding the first element for which `f` returns `true`.

If instead you use the function `fun (input, value) -> input >= 0` you'll hopefully find it will work as you expect.

Comment: @glennsi Thank you for the reply! What about a situation when I actually need to find a pair with first value (here named input) equal to 0? Is it impossible using this function?

Comment: `input >= 0` should do that. Does it not?

Comment: I guess you'd want it to fail/return `None` if no element with `input = 0` exists. Then this does not work directly, but you could easily check it afterwards. Since it finds the lowest element, if that does not have `input = 0` you know ti does not exist in the set.

Comment: `input >= 0` indeed does find a result. But as you said I would like it to return `None` if no element matches the predicate provided in the code snippet. Anyway this definitely answers my question. Thank you again for the comprehensive explanation.